# How calculate Price into Quantity for a JSON data and Post Data?

Tags: android, json, post

I am creating an Android application, and I am trying to retrieve data from a Restful Web-service through JSON.

I have performed a call with get and post JSON data from a Restful Web service(from a URL)
By [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/) Tutorial

So here I need to add price * quantity
like the example below:

[image]

But I don't know how to Post this calculation for JSON data
I googled and tried few Other options....
Can any one suggest me like this kind for Post JSON data..

I followed [this](https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/) to POST JSON Data

But this Should be Done OnClick, it should ask add enter quantity.
Offline(db) its possible But for Custom Listview(Async listview-Online) I am Unable to Build

Please let me Know to Use for this kind...
I google many options But I am Help less....

Comment: please comment below for don't down vote... I know all rules of stack overflow But here I am helpless... Please suggest me..

Comment: can you able to get data from json?no calculation. just data? are you able to fatch?

Comment: u want to post the json data from the 2 screenshot to the server ?

Comment: Yes sir,I can able to get and post But it should calculate and Post Total...

Comment: Your problem lies in 'calculating 6*80 (ie final bill) or you are failing where you were posting data to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood your question I'm trying to provide answer as follow. I hope that you understand Model class concept, which makes life easier.

**Step - 1 :**
First create one model class and make it Serializable to pass model object, because I can see that you have two activities one for products list and second for billing. In this you may add/remove some fields as per your requirements.

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    public String productName;
    public int price;
    public int quantity;
    public int total;
}
```

**Step - 2 :** Now I'm assuming that you know how to assign data to ArrayList userProducts by using **gson** library, [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544133/parsing-json-array-into-java-util-list-with-gson) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371274/how-to-parse-json-array-in-android-with-gson).

**Step - 3 :** Next step would be to calculate **total = price * quantity** in listview setOnItemClickListener like this,

```
Product product = userProducts.get(postiton);
product.total = product.price * product.quantity;
```

**Step - 4 :** Send arraylist with Serializable object from one activity to another,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ProductActivity.this, BillingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("user_products", userProducts);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Step - 5 :** Get values in billing activity,

```
    if (getIntent() != null) {
        userProducts = (ArrayList<Product>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("user_products");
    }
```

**Step - 6 :** Now your question is how to post them ? The thing is that you've to create jsonarray for list of products and jsonobject for some other fields, and then you can send main jsonobject as a string, a very good [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/).

```
    try {
        JSONObject mainJObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray productJArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < userProducts.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject productJObject = new JSONObject();
            productJObject.put("productname", userProducts.get(i).productName);
            productJObject.put("price", userProducts.get(i).price);
            productJObject.put("quantity", userProducts.get(i).quantity);
            productJObject.put("total", userProducts.get(i).total);
            productJArray.put(productJObject);
        }
        mainJObject.put("products", productJArray);
        mainJObject.put("grandd_total", grandTotal);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It should look like this,

```
        {
          "products": [
            {
              "productname": "p1",
              "price": "15",
              "quantity": "6",
              "total": 90
            },
            {
              "productname": "p2",
              "price": "25",
              "quantity": "4",
              "total": 100
            }
          ],
          "grandd_total": 190
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this json-structure data to post to the server:

```
{
"date": "2015-07-03",
"item": [
    {
        "itemname": "xyz",
        "quantity": 6,
        "price": 80
    },
    {
        "itemname": "abc",
        "quantity": 6,
        "price": 80
    }
],
"total": "960",
"currency": "Rs."
}
```

Comment: I have done this Sir But for Post Option I need to Calculate the amount and How I can calculate and Post Total   for a Restful data..

Answer (score 2):

Everything where money is involved you should use `BigDecimal` how you will post data to server really doesn't meather as long data are secured.

I would use volley lib. It take care of a lot of stuff instead of you and you should really dig into, it will save you a lot of time: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Also, I would use **GSON** for json objects. Its also simple for example create class:

```
 public class Money{
    String name;
    int quantay;
    BigDecimal rate;
    BigDecimal total;

    /* make seters and getters */
}
```

and the just create json like this:

```
money = new Money("name", 100, 0.54, 54);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(money);
```

thats it. Well you need constructor in Money class.

Answer (score 1):

how this answer help you.
you can read json right?

so by json object try this :-

```
    Double Rate = Double.parseDouble(jsonobject.getString("Rate"));//put api parameter
    int Qty= Integer.parseInt(jsonobject.getString("Qty"));
    Double total = Rate * Qty;
   //set total on your textview lable
    textview.settext(""+total);
```

and save in your local database and when you need to post then post your database to server.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather calculate the data before posting it to the php database. You can use something like the following:

```
double a = 1.50;
double b = 2.00;
double c = a * b;
```

Using the HTTPPost medthod *(which by the way is depreciated)* you need to then do something similar to the below:

```
public void postData(){  
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yourdomain.com/post.php");  

        try {
            List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data1", c));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);

            int current = 0;

            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }  

            text = new String(baf.toByteArray());
            txtvw.setText(text);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @codeByMi,.. Sir I am doing This for Online JSON data so it Possible,,,, If so Can you Update me.... Here I am Dealing with Price* Quantity.. Here Price is Dynamic and Quantity is User Input I need to Calculate both and POST them...

Comment: ok understood.

You can take 2 approaches to this. It all depends on whether you want to show the Price to the user or not. If yes, then I would recommend you to first call the php code to display the Price in the app. A good exmple is this: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579693/how-to-get-json-data-from-php-server-to-android-mobile`

Otherwise, if you don't wish to show the price in the app, you can perform the calculations on the php server. A good example for this is: `https://youtu.be/DqKkncDr-_k`

Comment: If you use the first approach, then you don't need to change the code above. Otherwise, you only need the value parameter to be sent to the PHP server.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you , as per above ans i have checked, you need `Grand_Total` to post on Bill `Webservice`.
you just calculate and pass that data to Bill Screen like above given ans

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
        userProducts = (ArrayList<Product>) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra("user_products");
    }
```

Here is one Grand Total is missing to pass as per looks in Billing screen

(Here we trying to get Grand total Rs.905)

```
double Grand_total = 0.0;

for(int i=0;i<userProducts.size();i++)
{
Product product = userProducts.get(postiton);
product.total = product.price * product.quantity;
Grand_total +=product.total;
}
```

Now you can pass all required data to Billing `webservice`  like

```
try {
        JSONObject mainJObject = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray productJArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < userProducts.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject productJObject = new JSONObject();
            productJObject.put("productname", userProducts.get(i).productName);
            productJObject.put("price", userProducts.get(i).price);
            productJObject.put("quantity", userProducts.get(i).quantity);
            productJObject.put("total", userProducts.get(i).total);
            productJObject.put("total", userProducts.get(i).total);

            productJArray.put(productJObject);
        }
        mainJObject.put("products", productJArray);
        mainJObject.put("Grand_total", Grand_total);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```