# Android Getting String from Response body using HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, python, flask, httpurlconnection

I have a flask server application which successfully returns a text string response.
In my android application it returns response code 200, however I can't seem to find where to retrieve the text being sent by flask in my connection response, what's the best way to retrieve the sent string in Android?

The following is the Android code making the POST

```
try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                InputStream inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceFileUri);
                URL url = new URL(uploadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)

                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.";

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //close the streams //
                inputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload  Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }
}
```

And the following is the Flask app returning the string

```
return Response(text, mimetype="text/html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by explicitly JSONifying my Flask app's response and then parsing it as the first answer of this question does [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579693/how-to-get-json-data-from-php-server-to-android-mobile)